# ArcMap 10.5.1 Export Feature Attribute to ASCII zeroes out certain columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, csv, arcgis-10.5

This is an export of about 20,000 points with 9 attributes to .csv.

Most fields come through perfectly fine, but two fields get filled with zeroes.  One has data type Double and the other is Long, and each holds numbers that are essentially integers (no decimal point).  Null values are not allowed.  Several other fields with the same characteristics are ok.

Is there anything I can change to get these fields to export properly, or is this a bug?

Before -- shapefile to export:

[image]

After -- exported .csv, sorted on column 7 to prove there are no other values:

[image]

Please note I selected only certain columns for export and did not bring along the field names.  Field 7 is PlotID and Field 9 is inner.  The duplicated columns are a little mysterious -- likely they were there but hidden.

Comment: Are there real values in the fields being changed to 0? You say Null values are not allowed so they can't be Null.. Can you give a screen shot of the table before and after conversion? How are you exporting to CSV?

Comment: Yes, they are real values.  I am using Export Feature Attribute to ASCII, but when I Select by Attribute for other purposes, the values populate the expression calculator as numeric.

Comment: Is the point feature class a shapefile? The DBF file can be opened with Microsoft Excel (and some other viewers) just **don't save the DBF file** as saving from Excel will corrupt the shapefile. It does sound a little odd that these values are being changed, it may well be a bug but I am hesitant to say that without seeing the values.

Comment: I'll be damned -- there are zeroes in the .dbf.  What do I do with that?  One of those columns was from a spatial join, the other -- I believe -- was field-calculated.  But the BO400 column was joined at the same time, and it's fine.

Comment: Are they the result of an attribute join by TARGET_FID to FID? Joining by FID in shapefiles is not a good idea as FID values are transient. What field type are the suspect fields?

Comment: The problem isn't just affecting this shapefile; it's a set of three, all built from the same process, all having the same export problem -- so it's not just a corrupt file.

Comment: No, spatial join.  And one is double, the other long.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here, but perhaps change the field names of your original file. I'm not sure how Export Feature Attribute to ASCII works under the hood, but when I searched for reserved words in shapefiles, there was a link on one of the help pages for reserved words in [Microsoft Jet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321266/list-of-microsoft-jet-4-0-reserved-words). It turns out INNER is a reserved word. Of course, that doesn't explain PlotID.

Comment: Are you currently editing the file? Like Fezter I'm clutching for straws.. this is truly odd behavior. Do tools like Table Select, Copy Rows or Table to Table cause the fields to blank (these don't export a CSV but I'm interested to see if the fields are affected by exporting per se or if it's an ASCII only problem.

Comment: I started from scratch and re-ran the entire workflow, copying over the offending columns to entirely new integer-type columns and changing "inner" to "holes."  Whatever was the problem, I now have the export I wanted.